# Position and orientation of robot in a grid

Tags: java, arrays, grid

I want to make a 10x10 grid and put the robot in position (10,1) (bottom left). I want this robot to be able to move forward, turn left/right and to pick up/put objects in a grid. When put in any position, there should be number in a grid which shows how many objects is put in this position, just like this:

```
..........
...1......
..2.......
....3.....
..........
..........
......9...
.....4....
.........1
..........
```

We will not see the robot in a grid. I have two classes. Class Robot:

```
public class Robot {

private Area area;
private Robot rob;

public Robot(Area area){
    this.area = area;
    rob = new Robot(area);
}

public void Right(){

}
public void Left(){

}
public void Forward(){

}
public void Put(){

}
public void PickUp(){

}
public (?) getPosition(){ // should return robot's position

}
}
```

Class Area:

```
private int numberOfObjects;
private Robot robot;
private static final int X = 10;
private static final int Y = 10;
private Object [][] area; // grid

public Area(){ // defines a grid and robot
    area = new Area[X][Y];
    for(int a=0;a<X;a++){
        for(int b=0;b<Y;b++)
            area[a][b]=".";
    }

    numberOfObjects = 0; // grid is initially empty
    Area ar = new Area();
    robot = new Robot(ar);
}

public void Put(int x,int y){ // put the object to position (x,y)
    area[x][y]=numberOfObjects++;
}

public void PickUp(int x,int y){ // pick up the object in position (x,y)
    if(area[x][y]!=null){
        area[x][y]=numberOfObjects--;
    }
}

public void PrintAGrid(){
    for(int r=0;r<X;r++){
        for(int c=0;c<Y;c++)
        System.out.print(area[r][c]+" ");
     System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

How can I put the robot in position (10,1)? How can I declare and set its orientation (i.e. on the right)? I guess it will be easy to write other methods, so I do not focus on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. Why do you have an instance of `Robot` inside the class `Robot`? You have not used that instance at all!
2. `private Object [][] area;` should be `int[][] area`. You always save `int` in this, right?
3. If I understand your requirements correctly, Your implementation of `pick` and `put` is not correct.

---

Here is a help how you can solve the problems. I had to think several times if `Robot` should be in `Grid` or it should be the other way. I ended up with `Grid` in `Robot`.
May be `Grid` could be a singleton.

Here is our `Grid`

```
public class Grid {
    private int[][] numberOfObjects = new int[10][10];

    public void put(int x, int y) {
        numberOfObjects[y][x]++;
    }

    public void pick(int x, int y) {
        numberOfObjects[y][x]--;
    }
}
```

You can replace parameters `int x, int y` with a `Point`.

And here is the robot

```
public class Robot {
    private static final int NORTH = 0, EAST = 1, SOUTH = 2, WEST = 3;
    private int direction;
    private int x, y;

    private Grid grid;

    public Robot(Grid grid) {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;

        this.grid = grid;
        direction = NORTH;
    }

    public void right() {
        direction++;
        if (direction == 4) {
            direction = 0;
        }
    }

    public void left() {
        direction--;
        if (direction == -1) {
            direction = 3;
        }
    }

    public void forward() {
        if (direction == NORTH) {
            y--;
        } else if (direction == SOUTH) {
            y++;
        } else if (direction == EAST) {
            x++;
        } else if (direction == WEST) {
            x--;
        }
    }

    public void put() {
        grid.put(x, y);
    }

    public void pick() {
        grid.pick(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Methods Right and Left should just turn the robot on the right/left, not move it. There is method Forward() to move with robot. Anyway, thank you for you help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @marek: Sorry i missed that part of your question. I am updating my answer in few minutes.

Comment: Yes, now it looks fine. I will do the rest of the program. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to represent the curent location with a variable and initialize it to the 10 1 postion, though your array goes 0-9 and 0-9 so this may be 9,0.  to store this position maybe try a Point object that contains a [Point x,y](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html).

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in a JavaScript version, you can have a look at this repo [right here](https://github.com/mkotsollaris/RobotGrid/blob/main/index.js). In general:

1. The robot must have a facing direction (`left`, `up`, `right`, `down`).
2. The are three possible commands: `left`, `right`, `move`.

With that being said, the algorithm is quite straightforward:

```
totalScore = 0
Foreach i in input
  computeCurrentDirection()
  if input != MOVE: continue
  totalScore += i

return totalScore
```

There are several sweet-tricks that someone might do to optimize the functions. Take a look at `switchDirection`.

```
const directionArray = [Directions.RIGHT, Directions.DOWN, Directions.LEFT, Directions.UP];

const switchDirection = (currDirection, command) => {
    if (command === Commands.MOVE) {
        return currDirection
    }

    const currDirectionIndex = directionArray.indexOf(currDirection);
    if (command === Commands.RIGHT) {
        return directionArray[(currDirectionIndex + 1) % 4];
    }
    return directionArray[((currDirectionIndex - 1) + 4) % 4];
}
```

Instead of an exhaustive approach, someone might use an array to help compute the upcoming direction of the robot. This *significantly* reduces the amount of needed code.

> Note this implementation can be easily expanded to accommodate any new requirements needed for project expansion. When faced with such questions, try to architect your codebase in a testable and expandable way, because it's usually the case where reviewers are interested in your coding organizational skills, rather than whether you are able to solve the problem or not.